# Sending a Broadcast from a Service to an Activity when the activity is between onDestroy - onCreate states

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, service, broadcastreceiver

This is going to be a little difficult to explain so I'll give you some context first.

**Context**

I'm developing an android application that basically what It does is give you a list of files (pdf files) from a server and you can download those files, synchronize the category of the files, which basically allows you to automatically download any new or updated file from that category or unsynchronize the files if you don't want to have any new update on some category.

**Application architecture**

I have a `Service` which is the one that takes charge of maintain every category updated, if you want to synchronize a new category then you send a message to the service. If the `Service` needs to notifie the `Activity` because some file is being downloaded, updated, has finished the download, or some other event, the `Service` will fire a `BroadcastReceiver` then the `Activity` will catch the `BroadcastReceiver` and will update the view. The service runs in Its own process, so the `Service` is always alive, event when the app is killed.

Heres a picture to explain my arch:

[image]

**The problem**

When the user chooses to unsynchronize a category, all the files associated with that category will be erased from disk, db and memory. The user does this by toogling a switch, when you toogle the switch a `Snackbar` will show up telling the user "The category X has been unsynchronized." and an action "Undo". Of curse, the category isn't really unsynchronized until the `Snackbar` dismiss callback is executed, this is in case that the user pressed the action "Undo". When the callback is executed a message is sent to the `Service` telling it to unsynchronize the category, the `Service` will perform the proper operations to erase all the stuff related to that category, and then It'll trigger a `BroadcastReceiver` to inform the `Activity` and thus the view that the operation has finished and now can update the views (FileDownloadReceiver, FileDownloadingReceiver, FileErrorReceiver, FileErasedRecever, etc.).

But if I rotate the screen while the snackbar is being shown, what'll happen is that, the `Snackbar` dismiss callback will send the message to the service, the `Activity` will unregister Its `BroadcastReceivers` in the `onDestroy` method, and then the `Service` will send the `BroadcastReceiver` to inform that the files were erased successfully, but the `onCreate` of the `Activity` hasn't been executed yet, so those `BroadcastReceivers` that were fired from the `Service` would be lost and the files in the `Activity` will end in an incorrect state, because the `Activity` never caught the `BroadcastReceiver` from the `Service`.

**What I tried so far**

Obviusly, using a `Handler` and putting the `sendBroadcast` inside a `Runnable` solves the problem. But It creates another bigger problem. If I do that, for example:

```
...
deleteAllFilesFromCategory(aCategory);
anErasedFile.setState(File.NOT_SYNCHRONIZED);
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        FileReceiver.sendFileErasedBroadcast(mContext, anErasedFile);   
    }
});
...
anErasedFile.setState(File.STATE_UNDEFINED);
...
```

I've the risk that when the `BroadcastReceiver` will be send, It'll do with an incorrect state, because is running in another thread.

I know that the problem maybe could be fixed if I don't rely in the `File` object that is being sent through the `Intent` of the broadcast, but the application has grown a lot and that's not possible now. I avoided a lot of business logic stuff and I simplified a lot what is really happening, but this is the main issue in a nutshell. If you want some specifics, you're free to ask me for them.

**The question**

How can I send a `BroadcastReceiver` from a `Service` to an `Activity` when the between the `onDestroy`, `onCreate` states of the `Activity` without using a `Handler`?

Comment: @pskink IDK about that, I googled It and I didn't found anything new, can you be more specific please?. If you mean switching to AIDL services kind I don't think that It will make any difference.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the last part. No, my service runs in It's own process. The main issue is that I the `Service` sends the broadcast after the Activity did the onDestroy and thus unbind the Receivers and before the Activity does the onCreate and thus bind the Receivers

Comment: And without my `Service` having Its own process, It'll be able of run in background even if my app is killed? Sorry I think that we're talking of different things, could you hand me a github repo or an example so I could check it out?

Comment: Maybe this is not the perfect solution but what about having broadcast receiver that has the intent you are listening for in manifest (that way you will always get notified) and the broadcast receiver will store the state persistently. The activity on the other hand can check the state from persistence (db, shared prefs) upon startup and register for online updates of the intent during its "on screen" state.

Comment: @Pskink Right, for example If I tap the recents button and I close my app. The Service needs to be able of continue running in background in that case

Comment: @MichaelLiberman That's a nice try, I'd thought in doing that but the main issue with that, is that It'd require doing unnecesary queries from db, the bottom line is, If I'm sending a File object through the intent of the broadcast I don't have any reason to make a query "just to be sure" that the state of the object is updated.

Comment: Yea, that may sounds a littly bit hacky but have you considered using EventBus with sticky events?

Comment: @Than Maybe, but I think that I'll have the same issue, I mean, with EventBus you do an `eventBus.register(this);` being `this` the context of the activity, in your onCreate and later an `eventBus.unregister(this)` in your onDestroy. Or you can avoid the `unregister` and just keep your activity hooked no matter what?

Comment: @astinx yes you're right, but since your event is sticky it will wait for you so you can handle it after activity rotation. https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/HOWTO.md#sticky-events

Comment: @Than Thanks I'll try doing something like what EventBus does, but the project is almost finished, there's no time to do a switch in the technologies. I need to fix this without doing any big change

Comment: It's not that hard, and i personally think EventBus is great replacement for Broadcasts

Comment: @Than neither `Broadcast`s nor `EventBus` should be used for `Activity` <-> `Service` communication, for that `Binder` interface should be used, see [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/bound-services.html) for more info

Comment: @pskink That's why i said it's hacky solution, however it's the easiest/fastest solution which fixes his problem. I didnt say it should be done that way.

Comment: @Than his problem is that he is not using ready for use components like `ContentProvider`s and `CursorLoader`s as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) which work out-of -the-box with no magic tricks